# Android Kotlin `.replaceRange` does not replace text in SpannableString

Tags: java, android, textview, kotlin

My Android application uses `ClickableSpan` to handle spoiler tags. I am trying to implement text replacement in `TextView` for it, but `.replaceRange` does nothing. I can confirm that `startPos` and `endPos` are valid positions.

```
        var text = ((textView as TextView).text as SpannableString)
        var spans = text.getSpans(0, text.length, SpoilerSpan::class.java)
        for (span in spans) {
            if (span == this) {
                val startPos = text.getSpanStart(span)
                val endPos = text.getSpanEnd(span)

                printout(startPos.toString() + " " + endPos.toString())

                text.replaceRange(startPos, endPos, spoilerText)
                printout(text.toString())
            }
        }
        textView.text = text
```

Comment: try `Editable#replace`

Comment: @pskink How can I cast it into Editable?

Comment: just like you did? `var text = ((textView as TextView).text as SpannableString)`

Comment: @pskink `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to android.text.Editable`

Comment: **SpannableString** - the docs say: *"This is the class for text whose content is immutable but to which markup objects can be attached and detached. For mutable text, see SpannableStringBuilder."* the key word here is *immutable*

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
text.replaceRange(startPos, endPos, spoilerText)
```

does nothing. It returns a new Object which you never use. See the documentation of the method. It returns a new object you should use like:

```
val newText = text.replaceRange(startPos, endPos, spoilerText)
```

The return type than is in your case a `CharSequence` (see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace-range.html). You have to deal with that.

---

JavaDoc of `SpannableString`:

> This is the class for text whose content is immutable but to which
>   markup objects can be attached and detached. For mutable text, see
>   SpannableStringBuilder.

So if the text must be mutable, use `SpannableStringBuilder` instead of `SpannableString`.
You can't use `replaceRange` either, because this returns a `CharSequence` what's usually not what one want, but the `SpannableStringBuilder` also has `replace` methods.

Comment: But I want to keep all my spans in textView. When I'll replace text with bare string returned by text.replaceRange, the markup will disapear

Comment: Than this is no option for you. The `replaceRange` is a immutable operation which always return a new object. In that case you should go with the way @pskink suggested.